# Does mysqli prepare cache results?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've read that if you used `mysqli` prepare instead of `mysqli` query it will be  run on database only once even if you run the script 1000 times.
does that mean that if i ran a prepare statement like

```
select * from Table where user=?"
and then mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", "Harry");
```

and user "harry" doesn't exist in the database so num_rows will return 0.and  then i insert immediately a new row in the database with `user="harry"` and ran the script again, will it `return num_rows=1` or still `return num_rows=0` because the result is cached?

Comment: What happens when you try it? (Ps. it doesn't cache)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you see the newly inserted row depends on other factors... transaction and transaction isolation. Preparing the statement just means that the server knows what is coming and has calculate a plan to optimize the statement. You can then run the query many times, with the same or with different parameters, and the server will not have to analyze it any more... just execute it.

So... to answer your question... the second time you should get num_rows=1. But in case you don't, the problem is not that you prepared a query with parameters... it's something else.

Comment: so if i refreshed the page with the prepare script after I inserted the new row the num_rows will be 1? and if it appeared 0 what could the error be?

Comment: SQL statements are executed in transactions (either explicit or implicit). If your reexecuted query does not see the new record, it probably means that the INSERT's transaction is still uncommitted... or that your SELECT is running in an old transaction.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand

Comment: Usually... SELECTs are executed in implicit transactions, which end when you fetch all records and/or close the query. OTOH INSERTs, UPDATEs, and DELETEs are often used within an explicit transaction (because you often want to write several things and be sure they all get written... or none). It is easier that the culprit be an explicit transaction handled incorrectly. But to be sure, you have to investigate and try to understand what's happening.

Comment: A transaction is used to tell the server that one or more statements have to be wrapped together. This has 2 purposes. The first is to be sure that they either get all executed correctly or that you can roll them all back as if nothing ever happened. The second purpose is to allow other applications or users to see a database which is stable, without all the continous updates the other applications/users are doing. Maybe you should check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction